# Как проверить, введено ли что-нибудь в поле?

Tags: javascript, html

Хотелось бы узнать, как проверить введено ли что-нибудь в тэге `input`. 
Я имею в виду, на регистрации аккаунта на названиях чего либо важного есть звездочка, и если пропустить то выскочит ошибка (это уже нашёл, не надо отвечать). А если написать все важные поля в форме, то будет наоборот. За этим я и пришёл сюда.
 
Код здесь: http://pastebin.com/GRBA4Mq7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**required** -  Устанавливает поле формы обязательным для заполнения перед отправкой формы на сервер. Если обязательное поле пустое, браузер выведет сообщение, а форма отправлена не будет.

```
<input type="text" required />
```

Comment: Не совсем хорошо, так как с использованием атрибута **required**, мы не узнаем какое именно из полей не заполнил пользователь, если например нам нужно вывести текст ошибки. А еще плохо то, что во всех браузерах по разному будет показывать ошибку.

Comment: @Abmin так в браузере сразу выдает не заполненное поле.

Comment: Лично я не использую required, так как хочу выводить "Вы не ввели имя" или "Выберите город".

Comment: Спасибо! Всё заработало!

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете проверять поля с помощью **javascript**, например так: *(код на jQuery)*

```
if($("#myinput").val() == "") {
  alert("поле с id myinput пустое");
}
```

Comment: это я уже нашел, как проверить введено ли вообще что-то на 3 полях, если да, отправить ответ капчи. Вы объяснили если нет.

Comment: @Wicopee, так же, только вместо `==` (равно) поставьте `!=` (не равно)

Comment: тоже спасибо, использую это в капче.